# How to use pastebin from shell script?

Tags: http, bash, shell, url, pastebin

Is it possible to use pastebin (may be via their ["API" functionality](http://www.pastebin.com/api.php)) inside bash shell scripts? How do I send http-post? How do I get back the URL?

Comment: FYI, pastebin.com is full of ads for anyone not using an appropriate browser plugin. Please consider using a different pastebin. http://ix.io/, f'rinstance, both (1) does not show ads, and (2) includes instructions for posting to it from major shells right on the homepage.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy The only problem with that is longevity. Pastebin is so far the only pastebin to have stood the test of time, having been around since 2002. Who knows how long these other tools are gonna last for before their respective sites go down from a DNS expiry, to a failure to pay the host (abandonment), to the host going bankrupt.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [documentation](http://pastebin.com/api.php) says that you need to submit a `POST` request to

```
http://pastebin.com/api_public.php
```

and the only mandatory parameter is `paste_code`, of type string is the paste that you want to make.

On success a new `pastebin` URL will be returned.

You can easily do this from your bash shell using the command `curl`.

`curl` uses the `-d` option to send the `POST` data to the specified URL.

**Demo:**

This demo will create a new paste with the code:

```
printf("Hello..I am Codaddict");
```

From your shell:

```
$ curl -d 'paste_code=printf("Hello..I am Codaddict");' 'http://pastebin.com/api_public.php'
http://pastebin.com/598VLDZp
$
```

Now if you see the URL http://pastebin.com/598VLDZp, you'll see my paste :)

**Alternatively** you can do it using the `wget` command which uses the option `--post-data` to sent `POST` values.

I've tried this command it works fine:

```
wget --post-data 'paste_code=printf("Hello..I am Codaddict");' 'http://pastebin.com/api_public.php'
```

Comment: This has now been disabled, there is a new Pastebin api

Comment: Details on the new API can be found here: https://pastebin.com/api. You need a `Developer API Key` at a minimum to be able to post. Have posted updated details below.

Answer (score 27):

As pastebin.com closed their public api, I was looking for alternatives.

[Sprunge](http://github.com/rupa/sprunge) is great. Usage:

```
<command> | curl -F 'sprunge=<-' http://sprunge.us
```

or, as I use it:

```
alias paste="curl -F 'sprunge=<-' http://sprunge.us"
<command> | paste
```

Comment: +1, with the caveat that it'd be better to provide a function than an alias -- functions can reorder arguments, do logic, be used in noninteractive shells, etc.

Comment: Getting "500 Internal Server error"
Also, last github commit was in 2014

Comment: If you want to use pastebin instead of sprunge, see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58440856/7872793)

Answer (score 7):

Put the following in your `.bashrc`:

```
sprunge() {
  if [[ $1 ]]; then
    curl -F 'sprunge=<-' "http://sprunge.us" <"$1"
  else
    curl -F 'sprunge=<-' "http://sprunge.us"
  fi
}
```

...and then you can run:

```
sprunge filename # post file to sprunge
```

...or...

```
some_command | sprunge # pipe output to sprunge
```

Answer (score 4):

https://paste.c-net.org/ has a simpler API than all of them. Simply "POST" to it.

From the website:

```
Upload text using curl:
$ curl -s --data 'Hello World!' 'https://paste.c-net.org/'

Upload text using wget:
$ wget --quiet -O- --post-data='Hello World!' 'https://paste.c-net.org/'

Upload a file using curl:
$ curl --upload-file @'/tmp/file' 'https://paste.c-net.org/'

Upload a file using wget:
$ wget --quiet -O- --post-file='/tmp/file' 'https://paste.c-net.org/'

Upload the output of a command or script using curl:
$ ls / | curl --upload-file - 'https://paste.c-net.org/'
$ ./bin/hello_world | curl -s --data-binary @- 'https://paste.c-net.org/'
```

You can also simply use netcat. Unlike termbin, paste.c-net.org won't time out if your script takes more than 5 seconds to produce its output.

```
$ { sleep 10; ls /; } | nc termbin.com 9999
$ { sleep 10; ls /; } | nc paste.c-net.org 9999
https://paste.c-net.org/ExampleOne
```

Answer (score 2):

The API for posting to pastebin has changed, since posted by codaddict.
Details can be found at this link: https://pastebin.com/api

Example:

`curl -d 'api_paste_code=printf("Hello..\n I am Codaddict");' \
     -d 'api_dev_key=<get_your_own>' \
     -d 'api_option=paste' 'http://pastebin.com/api/api_post.php'`

There are three essential fields as of now:
`api_dev_key` -> You need to create a login on pastebin.com in order to get that
`api_option` -> Format in which to post
`api_paste_code` -> Text you want to post

Answer (score 2):

Two other answers (from circa 2014) point to http://sprunge.us, which is designed to be used like this...

```
curl --form 'sprunge=@yourfile.txt' sprunge.us
```

However, as of 2018, sprunge.us has a tendency to be overloaded and return 500 Internal Server Error to every request. For files up to at least 300 KB but not as high as 2.8 MB, I have had good luck with the very similar service at http://ix.io:

```
curl --form 'f:1=@yourfile.txt' ix.io
```

For files up to at least 2.8 MB (and maybe higher, I don't know), I've found the more highly polished https://transfer.sh. It recommends a slightly different and simpler command line, and *requires* `https` (it won't work without it):

```
curl --upload-file yourfile.txt https://transfer.sh
```

Answer (score 2):

I have found that Sprunge is currently down, but [dpaste.com has a simple API](http://dpaste.com/api/v2/).

To post from STDIN

```
curl -s -F "content=<-" http://dpaste.com/api/v2/
```

from a file `foo.txt`

```
cat foo.txt | curl -s -F "content=<-" http://dpaste.com/api/v2/
```

to post a string

```
curl -s -F "content=string" http://dpaste.com/api/v2/
```

The response will be a plain text URL to the paste.

---

**Nb:** the trailing `/` in the URL `http://dpaste.com/api/v2/` seems necessary

Comment: There's also a  [dpaste.sh](https://hg.sr.ht/~paulbissex/dpaste-tools/browse/dpaste.sh) shell script that uses that API.

Answer (score 1):

## Easiest way to post to pastebin

```sh
echo 'your message' | sed '1s/^/api_paste_code=/g' | sed 's/$/\%0A/g' | curl -d @- -d 'api_dev_key=<your_api_key>' -d 'api_option=paste' 'http://pastebin.com/api/api_post.php'
```

Just change the `<your_api_key>` part and pipe whatever you want into it.

The `sed` invocations add the `api_paste_code` parameter to beginning of the message and add a newline at the end of each line so it can handle multiline input. The `@-` tells curl to read from stdin.

## A Bash Function You Can Paste

For easy reuse, make it a bash function (copy and paste this into your terminal and set the `API_KEY` field appropriately:

```sh
pastebin () {
  API_KEY='<your_api_key>'
  if [ -z $1 ]
  then
    cat - | sed '1s/^/api_paste_code=/g' | sed 's/$/\%0A/g' | curl -d @- -d 'api_dev_key='"$API_KEY"'' -d 'api_option=paste' 'http://pastebin.com/api/api_post.php'
  else
    echo "$1" | sed '1s/^/api_paste_code=/g' | sed 's/$/\%0A/g' | curl -d @- -d 'api_dev_key='"$API_KEY"'' -d 'api_option=paste' 'http://pastebin.com/api/api_post.php'
  fi
  printf '\n'
}
```

You can run it with either:

`pastebin 'your message'`

or if you need to pipe a file into it:

`cat your_file.txt | pastebin`

Comment: Can you use pastebin with the api-key in a way that the URL you have is always the same?
Let's say I want to share a textfile within every minute via pastebin, but the other party does only know one hardcoded pastebin URL. Is that possible?

Comment: Idk if you can use a fixed url. You’d have to check pastebin’s api documentation. Let me know what you find out @cs.lev

Comment: I figured out, it turns out that pastebin does not support that...only new pastes can be made and old ones can be deleted :S
I changed to github gists and git pull/push commands instead :)

Answer (score 1):

To built upon Vishal's answer, pastebin has upgraded to only use HTTPS now:

```
curl -d 'api_paste_code=printf("Hello World");' \
     -d 'api_dev_key=<your_key>' \
     -d 'api_option=paste' 'https://pastebin.com/api/api_post.php'
```

You don't have to specify the `-X POST` parameter

Additional details can be found here:
https://pastebin.com/doc_api#1

Answer (score 0):

Based on [another answer on this page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64366391/5353461), I wrote the following script which reads from STDIN (or assumes output it piped into it).

This version allows for arbitrary data which is URI escaped (by `jq`).

```
#!/bin/bash

api_key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

curl -d "api_paste_code=$(jq -sRr @uri)" \
     -d "api_dev_key=$api_key" \
     -d 'api_option=paste' 'https://pastebin.com/api/api_post.php'

echo  # By default, there's no newline
```

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit late to this post, but I created a little tool to help with this.

https://pasteshell.com/

Feel free to check it out and let me know what you think.

Thanks,

Comment: service is dead

Comment: It is still running. Can you please let me know what does not work for you. Really interested in your feedback.

Comment: ok. it's back now. the website timed out last time i visited the domain with a browser (on december 3rd).